# Как найти и переслать сообщение с другого chatid (telebot)?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot, чат

Всем привет

Только учусь делать ботов и столкнулся с проблемой.

Функционал бота, казалось бы, простой:

1. Пользователь пишет сообщение
2. Бот ищет текст, который написал пользователь, в другом чате (по chatid)
3. И пересылает найденное сообщение пользователю

Получилось реализовать поиск и пересылку сообщения из своего чата, но совсем не выходит реализовать это с другим.

Перед тем, как сюда писать, несколько часов искал информацию в интернете и мучил chatgpt, руки уже опускаются

Заранее спасибо за помощь

Comment: Если мне память не изменяет, то бот может взаимодействовать только с теми чатами в которых непосредственно добавлен.

Comment: Не так выразился. Не чат, а личные сообщения

Comment: Сообщение можно отправлять только тем пользователям которые взаимодействовали с ботам. Просто так отправить рандомному человеку сообщение нельзя. Вы конечно можете написать пользовательскую часть и писать сообщения от своего лица, но это быстрый путь в бан если будете спамить.